# What verb can I use to indicate the process of putting together boards, work groups, etc?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, verbs

What verb can I use to indicate the process of putting together boards, work groups etc? That is, what verb goes in the slot in the following examples?

1. Bodies that are _____ through election shall...
2. When boards are ______...

I realise that I can always rephrase, but I'd like to know if there is, in fact, a verb I can use in this exact way. Note that I don't mean the original creation of a new board/body, but the process of "staffing" a certain body, whether it's a new body, or one that has been around for a while.

Comment: Being elected, and being appointed, to a position are different.

Comment: "Bodies _whose members_ are appointed..." (but, as Michael says, they are either elected or appointed, not both.)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right, so which verb could I use instead? Meaning 'put together' – i.e. "Bodies that are put together through election".

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, like I said: I realise I can rephrase, but I'd like to know if there is a verb I can use in this precise way... though I guess I mean 'put together' rather than 'appoint' :)

Comment: What's wrong with 'elected bodies' or 'appointed bodies'?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether OP's context involves simply ***replacing the personnel*** who constitute the "board of directors" / "ruling body" of some organisation that already exists, OR "putting together" (by election, appointment, or whatever) a group of people to create / administer some ***new*** "body, group, organisation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Either! :) It's really hard to explain what I'm after, because the precise reason that I'm asking is because I don't know a word in English that covers what I need... which doesn't make it any easier for you to help me, I gues :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms of the verbs "choose" or "select" could be used.

Versions of text 1  might be:

> - Bodies that are chosen through election shall...
> - Bodies that are selected through election shall...

Versions of text 2  might be:

> - When boards are appointed ...
> - When boards are chosen by appointment ...
> - When boards are selected by appointment ...

Other verbs might be used, but  I think those would be the most common for this construction.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need a word to fill in the blank, the closest I can come up with is "**assembled**."

It's not particularly idiomatic to say that a body is "assembled through election," though. It would likely be better to rephrase the point in a more natural way, as a number of comments have suggested.

Comment: Thank you! What about "constituted" then (see the comments to Michael Harvey's answer)?

Comment: Constituted is also generally ok, but "constituted through election" is not any smoother than the above. "Through election" is the problem. It's understandable, but it's not what people say.

Comment: Thank you again! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In British English, you can discuss the individual members of an appointed body, or the body itself as a singular thing.

> Parole Board members are appointed, by ministers, under Schedule 19 of
> the Criminal Justice Act 2003
>
> The Parole Board is appointed by ministers.

Comment: Thank you!! Now that I understand that "appoint" is rather narrow in its meaning, I'm wondering whether there is a more general verb though, that refers to the process of putting together a board, whether by election or appointment?

Comment: @Lillatanten - When they are created, you can say more formally that they are constituted.

Comment: Thanks again! So... would "Bodies that are constituted through election" work? To me, that sounds odd, but I don't really trust my intuition here :)

Comment: A body that was constituted by Parliament could have members appointed or elected to it.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! So "Bodies that are constituted through election" would work?